# Ember.js passing 'each' variable into component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In my Ember app, I'm trying to make a `view-picks-row` component for each item in my array `picks`. It looks like this:

```
{{#each picks as |playerPicks|}}
  {{view-picks-row player=playerPicks, incorrect=incorrect, correct=correct, round=1}}
{{/each}}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 26:
...ew-picks-row player=playerPicks, incorre
-----------------------^
Expecting 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'
```

Am I not allowed to pass `each` variables into a component? What would be the preferred way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to specify comma

```
{{view-picks-row player=playerPicks incorrect=incorrect correct=correct round=1}}
```